# fill cells containing nan with average of values immediately before and after

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a question very similar to
[Fill cell containing NaN with average of value before and after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44032771/fill-cell-containing-nan-with-average-of-value-before-and-after)
the only addition being that several entries in a row might be NaNs, and then the replacement should be done with averages too, or better with linearly adjusted averages, for example:
    [1, nan, nan, 4, ...] should become [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
and
    [8, nan, nan, 2, ...] should become [8, 6, 4, 2, ...]
etc. Is this still possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html#pandas-dataframe-interpolate):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,np.nan, np.nan, 4],'B':[8,np.nan,np.nan,2]})


     A    B
0  1.0  8.0
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
3  4.0  2.0


df.interpolate()
```

Output:

```
     A    B
0  1.0  8.0
1  2.0  6.0
2  3.0  4.0
3  4.0  2.0
```