# pandas filling nans by mean of before and after non-nan values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to fill `df`'s `nan` with an average of adjacent elements.

Consider a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [1,np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan, 10, 1,2,5, np.nan, np.nan, 9]})
    val
0   1.0
1   NaN
2   4.0
3   5.0
4   NaN
5   10.0
6   1.0
7   2.0
8   5.0
9   NaN
10  NaN
11  9.0
```

My desired output is:

```
    val
0   1.0
1   2.5
2   4.0
3   5.0
4   7.5
5   10.0
6   1.0
7   2.0
8   5.0
9   7.0 <<< deadend
10  7.0 <<< deadend
11  9.0
```

I've looked into other solutions such as [Fill cell containing NaN with average of value before and after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44032771/fill-cell-containing-nan-with-average-of-value-before-and-after), but this won't work in case of two or more consecutive `np.nan`s.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you actually want two or more consecutive `NaN` to be filled with the same value? Don't you actually want a linear interpolation between the defined values?

Comment: @pipe I did think of it but seemed over-complicated and computationally heavier than filling with `average`, which it not necessary, as my actual dataset can go over tens of millions of rows.

Comment: df.val.interpolate(limit=1).fillna(method="ffill")

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) + [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) and divide by 2:

```
df = (df.ffill()+df.bfill())/2

print(df)
     val
0    1.0
1    2.5
2    4.0
3    5.0
4    7.5
5   10.0
6    1.0
7    2.0
8    5.0
9    7.0
10   7.0
11   9.0
```

**EDIT :** If 1st and last element contains `NaN` then use ([`Dark`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54414269/pandas-filling-nans-by-mean-of-before-and-after-non-nan-values/54414323#comment95639230_54414323)
 suggestion):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val':[np.nan,1,np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan, 
                          10, 1,2,5, np.nan, np.nan, 9,np.nan,]})
df = (df.ffill()+df.bfill())/2
df = df.bfill().ffill()

print(df)
     val
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    2.5
3    4.0
4    5.0
5    7.5
6   10.0
7    1.0
8    2.0
9    5.0
10   7.0
11   7.0
12   9.0
13   9.0
```

Comment: If first and last elements are `nan`. Then use `df.bfill().ffill()` after using the above solution.

Answer (score 6):

Althogh in case of multiple `nan`'s in a row it doesn't produce the exact output you specified, other users reaching this page may actually prefer the effect of the method `interpolate()`:

```
df = df.interpolate()

print(df)
     val
0    1.0
1    2.5
2    4.0
3    5.0
4    7.5
5   10.0
6    1.0
7    2.0
8    5.0
9    6.3
10   7.7
11   9.0
```