# Pandas replace zero as the nearest average non-zero value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,0,15,0,0,12,0,0,0,5]})
```

And I want to replace the 0 value with the nearest non zero value,

For example, the first value is 0, then I find the the nearest non-zero value is 15, so I replace it as 15, then the data becomes:`[15,0,15,0,0,12,0,0,0,5],`

Then for all the value except first one, I need to find the both side of the nearest non-zero value, and average them. So for the second 0, it would be (15+15)/2; And the third zero would be (15+12)/2

I only know how to replace zero to the nearest value by:

```
df['A'].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')

0     0
1     0
2    15
3    15
4    15
5    12
6    12
7    12
8    12
9     5
```

But the first two zero value cannot be replaced, and this way is not getting the average value.

Comment: This is not something conventional, so you have to write a loop for this since you have to go through many iterations.

Comment: To add to above comment, it is basically writing your own short algo. where you need to check each element, it's nearby element and then perform operations

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54414269/pandas-filling-nans-by-mean-of-before-and-after-non-nan-values/54414323#54414323

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not exactly the same, it seems like a good solution to your problem would be to apply a [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).

You could use [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html), which by default performs a linear interpolation, setting `limit_direction` to `both` so it fills both forward and backward:

```
df['A'] = df.A.interpolate(limit_direction='both')

     A
0  15.00
1  15.00
2  15.00
3  14.00
4  13.00
5  12.00
6  10.25
7   8.50
8   6.75
9   5.00
```