# KNNImputer with scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a measurement of an engine with 14 different sensors and an measuring intervall of 6 seconds, which is presented as a numpy-array with 14 columns and approximately 5000 rows. Each row represents a measuring point and each column represents a feature.

1% of the dataset are NaNs and I would like to impute them to use them with a SVM.

Because the dataset is a time series of a dynamic engine, it only makes sense to look at the 2 nearest datapoints of the missing value: one datapoint before and one datapoint after. It should calculate the mean value of the 2 nearest datapoints.

I thought this should be possible with the KNNImputer of scikit-learn, but I'm not satisfied when I have a complete row of NaNs. Look at this example:

```
15.30      80.13   20000.00   15000.00     229.00     698.00     590.00      24.00      82.53      1522.00     410.00     406.00     407.00      50.01
nan        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan
15.30      82.90   20000.00   15000.00     225.00     698.00     628.00      24.00      85.36    1523.00     410.00     407.00     408.00      50.02
```

The output of the KNNImputer looks like this:

```
15.30      80.13   20000.00   15000.00     229.00     698.00     590.00      24.00      82.53    1522.00     410.00     406.00     407.00      50.01
19.90      91.88   19997.09   19945.58     327.14     829.40     651.23      25.97      94.80    1529.65     410.20     406.69     407.72      49.99
15.30      82.90   20000.00   15000.00     225.00     698.00     628.00      24.00      85.36    1523.00     410.00     407.00     408.00      50.02
```

Looking at the first column I would except for the NaN: (15.30 + 15.30)/2=15.30

Instead I got 19.90.

My code:

```
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer

imp = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2)  
X_afterImputer = imp.fit_transform(X_beforeImputer)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What if you pass n=1?

Comment: @mkrieger1 same result

Comment: Found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54414323/12526784 Thanks anyway for your response ;)

Comment: Duplicate of [pandas filling nans by mean of before and after non-nan values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54414269/pandas-filling-nans-by-mean-of-before-and-after-non-nan-values)

Comment: @mkrieger1 OP specifically said that he uses a NumPy array

Comment: @NicolasGervais they also said that the linked q&a solved their problem

Comment: That doesn't make it a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a lot of noise because of the low n-neighbour value you are passing. However, keep in mind the method is not expected to return the mean between the top and bottom row necessarilly. The model which is trained with the data, will obviously have a lot of noise that will make it differ from the value you seem to be expecting. (The KNNImpute value is not calculated as: `((x-1) + (x+1))/2`. Instead you could try and use `.fillna(df.mean())`

Comment: Thanks, but with pandas it will result in the mean of the _whole_ column and I want just the mean of the value previous and after

Answer (score 1):

I made a function for you. Here's a reproducible example so you can see how it works:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 4)).astype(float)

arr[2, 0] = np.nan
arr[4, 3] = np.nan
arr[0, 2] = np.nan

print(arr)
```

```py
[[ 5.  7. nan  4.]
 [ 2.  6.  4.  9.]
 [nan  2.  5.  5.]
 [ 7.  0.  3.  8.]
 [ 6.  4.  3. nan]
 [ 8.  1.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  2.  6.  6.]
 [ 8.  1.  9.  7.]
 [ 3.  5.  8.  8.]]
```

```py
for x in np.argwhere(np.isnan(arr)):
    sample = arr[np.maximum(x[0] - 1, 0):np.minimum(x[0] + 2, 20), x[1]]
    arr[x[0], x[1]] = np.mean(sample[np.logical_not(np.isnan(sample))])
print(arr)
```

```py
[[5.  7.  4.  4. ] # 3rd value here is mean(4)
 [2.  6.  4.  9. ]
 [4.5 2.  5.  5. ] # first value here is mean(2, 7)
 [7.  0.  3.  8. ]
 [6.  4.  3.  4. ] # 4th value here is mean(8, 0)
 [8.  1.  2.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  1.  1. ]
 [1.  2.  6.  6. ]
 [8.  1.  9.  7. ]
 [3.  5.  8.  8. ]]
```

The logic is as follows:

```
for every location (x, y) where value is missing:
    take previous and next value (if possible)
    assign the mean of these two values to the location (x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the latest version of `sklearn` and this method is not available but here are 2 suggestions:

- Use: `n_neighbors=1`
- Use `pandas`

```
X = np.array([[2, np.nan], [3, 4], [np.nan, 6], [8, 8]]) 
array([[ 2., nan],
       [ 3.,  4.],
       [nan,  6.],
       [ 8.,  8.]])

X=pd.DataFrame(X)
X = X.fillna(X.mean())
X.values
array([[2.        , 6.        ],
       [3.        , 4.        ],
       [4.33333333, 6.        ],
       [8.        , 8.        ]])
```

Comment: Tanks, but with n_neighbors=1 I got the same result. With pandas it will result in the mean of the _whole_ column and I want just the mean of the value previous and after