# fillna with rolling mean of a group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, moving-average

I have a data frame with date time and would like to fill the missing values with the rolling average of the two rows around the row with nans - at the same time time though (therefore need the groupby time). The below unfortunately does not work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':['2023-04-20 13:00', '2023-04-21 13:00','2023-04-22 13:00', '2023-04-23 13:00','2023-04-21 14:00', '2023-04-22 14:00', '2023-04-23 14:00'], 'var':[1, 2, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 4, 5]})

df = df.assign(datetime=pd.to_datetime(df.datetime))
df = df.assign(time=df['datetime'].dt.time)

#does not work
df.assign(var=df.groupby('time', sort=False).var.apply(lambda col: col.fillna(col.rolling(window=2, center=2).mean())))
```

so I have this

```
            datetime    var
0   2023-04-20 13:00    1.0
1   2023-04-21 13:00    2.0
2   2023-04-22 13:00    NaN
3   2023-04-23 13:00    3.0
4   2023-04-21 14:00    NaN
5   2023-04-22 14:00    4.0
6   2023-04-23 14:00    5.0
```

and would like to have this

```
            datetime    var
0   2023-04-20 13:00    1.0
1   2023-04-21 13:00    2.0
2   2023-04-22 13:00    2.5
3   2023-04-23 13:00    3.0
4   2023-04-21 14:00    4.0
5   2023-04-22 14:00    4.0
6   2023-04-23 14:00    5.0
```

Also is there an option to increase the window size over which I want to take the mean?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44033052/8353711) `df.var.fillna((df.var.shift() + df.var.shift(-1))/2)`?

Comment: It does not take into account that I would like to have the mean over the rows with the same time

Comment: don't fillna inside `groupby.apply`, rather, just calculate the rolling mean: `means=groupby()['var'].rolling(window_size).mean()`, then `df['var'] = df['var'].fillna(means)`.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use `pd.Series.interpolate` with `limit_direction='both'`

```py
df["var"] = df.groupby("time", group_keys=False)["var"].apply(
    pd.Series.interpolate, limit_direction="both"
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             datetime  var      time
0 2023-04-20 13:00:00  1.0  13:00:00
1 2023-04-21 13:00:00  2.0  13:00:00
2 2023-04-22 13:00:00  2.5  13:00:00
3 2023-04-23 13:00:00  3.0  13:00:00
4 2023-04-21 14:00:00  4.0  14:00:00
5 2023-04-22 14:00:00  4.0  14:00:00
6 2023-04-23 14:00:00  5.0  14:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you define the window size with interpolate? I actually would like to have it bigger than just one in each direction (that was just here in the example as the df is so small).